# WCF Async method: wait until the operation is complete

Tags: wcf

I want to wait until an asynchronous WCF Service operation is complete. How to do that ?

```
Service.WebService.GetUserCompleted += new EventHandler<BGWebService.GetUserCompletedEventArgs>(WebService_GetUserCompleted);
Service.WebService.GetUserAsync(UserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated method `GetUserAsync` should return an `IAsyncResult` ([see MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx)). You can use that to block until the operation completes:

```
IAsyncResult asyncResult = Service.WebService.GetUserAsync(UserId);
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Comment: I tried it already, but I can't cast the GetUserAsync from the void type to IAsyncResult

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried doing this in a different way. Rather than waiting for the service response I had it send a call to the interface I was working on.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Calling the service to get the object needed
    private string personname
        public string PersonName 
        {
            get {
                return personname;
            }
            set {
                personname = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PersonName");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void LoadMembersName() 
        {
            ServiceSoapClient serviceClient = new ServiceSoapClient() {};
            serviceClient.GetMembersNameCompleted += (sender, e)=>{
            PersonName = e.Result
        } ;
    }
}
```

Now on the interface we just need to load the person's name and perform the operations after the property change event triggers.

```
void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person per = new Person();
    per.PropertyChanged += (sender,e) =>
    {
        //Your code here 
        Response.Write(per.PersonName);
    };
    per.LoadMembersName();
}
```

I am really sorry. I too had copied the code from some source, but I have misplaced the link.